# Compute the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{3^x+2^x-2}{4^x+2^x-2}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Compute the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{3^x+2^x-2}{4^x+2^x-2}$

Here is what I have done so far:
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{3^x+2^x-2}{4^x+2^x-2}
&=
\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{3^x-1}{4^x+2^x-2}+\frac{2^x-1}{4^x+2^x-2}\right)\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{3^x-1}{x}\frac{x}{4^x+2^x-2}+\frac{2^x-1}{x}\frac{x}{4^x+2^x-2}\right)\\
&=\ln 3\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{4^x+2^x-2}+\ln 2\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{4^x+2^x-2}
\end{align}

Comment: use maths jax @Robert

Comment: I get a message that tells me "missing close brace"

Comment: Judging by the tag I'm assuming you don't want to use L'hopital?

Comment: @Landuros I've not been taught how to use it, and this exercice is not supposed to be solved with it

Comment: You are on the good track, use the same method for the denominator!

Comment: @gimusi It worked ! I' ll mark your answer as accepted asap

Comment: @Robert well done, we have given some trick here to do it shorter but your idea to use standar limits is very nice! Bye

Comment: Please see "how to write a good question" at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question . In particular, there is no question in the post as currently written, just a summary of what you had done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that by standard limits since

$$\frac{a^x-1}{x}\to \log a$$

we have that

$$\frac{3^x+2^x-2}{4^x+2^x-2}=\frac{\frac{3^x-1}x+\frac{2^x-1}x}{\frac{4^x-1}x+\frac{2^x-1}x}\to\frac{\log 3+\log2}{\log 4+\log 2}=\frac{\log 6}{\log 8}$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{3^x+2^x-2}{4^x+2^x-2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\frac{3^x-1}{x}+\frac{2^x-1}{x}}{\frac{4^x-1}{x}+\frac{2^x-1}{x}}=\frac{\ln3+\ln2}{\ln4+\ln2}=\log_86$$
I used $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{a^x-1}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\left(\frac{e^{x\ln{a}}-1}{x\ln{a}}\cdot\ln{a}\right)=\ln{a}$$ for all $a>0$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{3^x+2^x-2}{4^x+2^x-2}&=\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{3^x-1}{4^x+2^x-2}+\frac{2^x-1}{4^x+2^x-2}\right)
\\&=\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{3^x-1}{x}\frac{x}{4^x+2^x-2}+\frac{2^x-1}{x}\frac{x}{4^x+2^x-2}\right)
\\&=\ln 3\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{4^x+2^x-2}+\ln 2\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{4^x+2^x-2} \\&= (\ln 3 + \ln 2) \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{x}{4^x+2^x-2} 
\\&= (\ln 3 + \ln 2) \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1}{\frac{4^x-1}{x}+\frac{2^x-1}{x}} \\
&=\frac{\ln 3 + \ln 2}{\ln 4 + \ln 2} \\
&= \frac{\ln 6}{\ln 8}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

*Just added for your curiosity since you already received good answers.*

Since $$a^x=e^{x \log(a)}$$ using Taylor series around $x=0$
$$a^x=1+ \log (a)x+\frac{1}{2} \log ^2(a) x^2+O\left(x^3\right)$$ This makes
$$A=\frac{3^x+2^x-2}{4^x+2^x-2} =\frac{ (\log (2)+\log (3))x+\frac{1}{2}  \left(\log ^2(2)+\log
   ^2(3)\right)x^2+O\left(x^3\right) } {(\log (2)+\log (4))x+\frac{1}{2}  \left(\log ^2(2)+\log
   ^2(4)\right)x^2+O\left(x^3\right)  }$$ Divide top and bottom by $x$ and make the long division to get, after simplifications,
$$A=\frac{\log (6)}{\log (8)}-\frac{ \log \left(\frac{4}{3}\right) \log
   (54)}{18 \log (2)}x+O\left(x^2\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached.

But you can use it for approximation. For illustration, use $x=0.1$. This would give $A\approx 0.852457$ while the exact value would be $A\approx 0.852248$.

Comment: I don't know anything about Taylor series at the moment

Comment: @Robert. Don't worry ! You will learn about them quite soon and I hope and wish you will enjoy them as much as I do (I felt in love with  Taylor series more than 60 years ago). Just remember that all problems with limits can be solved with them and that, for almost the same price, you can get the asymptotics. Cheers and good luck in your studies.