# Compute the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2^x+5^x-4^x-3^x}{5^x+4^x-3^x-2^x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function, fractions, limits-without-lhopital

I don't know how to start, i've noticed that it can be written as $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2^x+5^x-4^x-3^x}{5^x+4^x-3^x-2^x}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(5^x-3^x)+(2^x-4^x)}{(5^x-3^x)-(2^x-4^x)}$$

Comment: If you believe Michael's answer was exactly what you were looking for, tick it $\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Comment: @Arthur I always had to wait five minutes...

Comment: try to relate your question with the previous [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2664317/306553), they are almost asking for the same trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{2^x+5^x-4^x-3^x}{5^x+4^x-3^x-2^x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\frac{2^x-1}{x}+\frac{5^x-1}{x}-\frac{4^x-1}{x}-\frac{3^x-1}{x}}{\frac{5^x-1}{x}+\frac{4^x-1}{x}-\frac{3^x-1}{x}-\frac{2^x-1}{x}}=$$
$$=\frac{\ln2+\ln5-\ln4-\ln3}{\ln5+\ln4-\ln3-\ln2}.$$
I used $$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{a^x-1}{x}=\ln{a}\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{e^{x\ln{a}}-1}{x\ln{a}}=\ln{a}$$ for $a>0$.

Comment: Very nice, I can't belive i didn't notice

Comment: I know this is not explicitly l'Hopital, but it's awfully close. It would be nice if you can add some details on how it's different.

Comment: I added something It's the definition of $(e^x)'_{x=0}.$

Comment: @Robert if you believe Michael's answer was exactly what you were looking for, tick it $\color{green}{\checkmark}$

Comment: @user477343 I think he has to wait until the question is ten minutes old.

Comment: @Arthur for me, it's five minutes.

Comment: In 2 minutes guys

Comment: @user477343 That may be. I don't remember exactly. At any rate, he doesn't _have_ to do it immediately, as you seem to think. I think it's just common courtesy to give other people at least some time to write their own answers. Maybe someone is composing a very detailed one right now. If so, seeing this short answer marked accepted will probably discourage them. I have often waited a day when I've asked questions.

Comment: @Arthur I know he doesn't have to do it immediately, but I just think Michael is well deserving of a tick is all. And it is pretty obvious as to why we have to wait before we could tick. LATEX takes time to write, as I have noticed...

Answer (score 1):

This is a very special case of l’Hôpital’s theorem, possibly what gave him (or Bernoulli) the idea for the general case.

If you have two functions $f$ and $g$ which are differentiable at $0$ (or any other point), then
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{g(x)-g(0)}=\frac{f'(0)}{g'(0)}
$$
provided $g'(0)\ne0$ (if $g'(0)=0$, it's another story). The link with the general theorem should be apparent.

However, this is *not* l’Hôpital: the proof is very easy, because one notices that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{g(x)-g(0)}=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\,\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\,}{\,\dfrac{g(x)-g(0)}{x}\,}=
\frac{f'(0)}{g'(0)}
$$
by standard limit theorems.

Thus your limit boils down to considering $f(x)=2^x+5^x-4^x-3^x$ and $g(x)=5^x+4^x-3^x-2^x$, since $f(0)=0$ and $g(0)=0$. Then the limit is
$$
\frac{\log2+\log5-\log4-\log3}{\log5+\log4-\log3-\log2}
$$

*But I can’t use derivatives!* you might object. Well, it happens that taking the derivative is considered an application of l’Hôpital, but actually it isn’t, as shown before. I use to say that when we know derivatives we are able to compute limits of several sorts, so why avoiding them?

If you can't use derivatives, just pretend you don't. Let's look at $f$; it is a sum of functions. How do you prove that the derivative of a sum is the sum of the derivatives?

Suppose you have $a(x)$ and $b(x)$, with $s(x)=a(x)+b(x)$ (always at $0$, but it's the same at every point):
$$
\frac{s(x)-s(0)}{x-0}=\frac{(a(x)-a(0))+(b(x)-b(0))}{x}=
\frac{a(x)-a(0)}{x}+\frac{b(x)-b(0)}{x}
$$
If the function are four, say $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$, with $s=a+b+c+d$, then
$$
\frac{s(x)-s(0)}{x-0}=
\frac{a(x)-a(0)}{x}+\frac{b(x)-b(0)}{x}+
\frac{c(x)-c(0)}{x}+\frac{d(x)-d(0)}{x}
$$
Now you see how to hide the derivative under the carpet:
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2^x+5^x-4^x-3^x}{5^x+4^x-3^x-2^x}
=
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\dfrac{2^x-1}{x}+\dfrac{5^x-1}{x}-\dfrac{4^x-1}{x}-\dfrac{3^x-1}{x}}{\dfrac{5^x-1}{x}+\dfrac{4^x-1}{x}-\dfrac{3^x-1}{x}-\dfrac{2^x-1}{x}}
$$

You *know* that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{r^x-1}{x}=\log r
$$
is the derivative at $0$ of $x\mapsto r^x$, don't you?